# Validation is never fired

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Car(models.Model):
  manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, blank = True, null = True)
```

My serialisers:

```
class ManufacturerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Manufacturer
    fields = ('id', 'name')

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  manufacturer = Manufact  

  class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'manufacturer')

  def validate(self, attrs):
    try:
      attrs['manufacturer'] = Manufacturer.objects.get(pk = attrs['manufacturer'])
    except Manufacturer.DoesNotExist:
      raise ValidationError(_('Not found'))

    return attrs
```

My views:

```
class CarList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = Car.objects.all()
  serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

When I try to add a new `Car calling POST /cars/` I get a validation error `manufacturer` is a required field. `Car` model expects `manufacturer` field to be `Manufacturer` object but to make messages small I pass it the `manufacturer_id` instead.

I know that should raise a `ValidationError` so to fix this I added a `validate(..)` to my `CarSerializer` so during validation I check if `Manufacturer` by this ID exists and I assign it to attrs.

Problem is this `validate(..)` is never called I even tried adding a `post()` method to `CarList` view and manually calling `is_valid()` to no success.

But I still get validation errors which I assume are coming from the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are complicating things. The `ManufacturerSerializer` is not necessary (for this view anyway). [By default](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#relational-fields) the `'manufacturer'` field will be represented as a [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) which will resolve your `manufacturer_id` to a `Manufacturer` object automatically, so you don't need your `validate` method either.

Updated serializers:

```
class CarPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'manufacturer')

class CarGetSerializer(CarPostSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer()
```

Updated view:

```
class CarList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CarPostSerializer
        else:
            return CarGetSerializer
```

Comment: Bloody hell it worked. But what about when I do a `GET /cars/` request I get `manufacturer: 1` Instead of `manufacturer: { name: "BMW", country: "Germany", ...}`

Comment: That is correct. To use different serializers override the `get_serializer_class` method on your view and check if it's a GET or a POST. Or do a second `GET /manufacturer/[pk]/` to fetch details (after creating that view of course).

Comment: So I need two CarSerializers one where I have manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer() and one without that line ? Than In view I check if it's a POST or GET and load appropriate or ?

Comment: Exactly. The "GET serializer" could be a subclass of the "POST serializer", just adding the nested field, i e "manufacturer =Manufacturerserializer()"

Comment: Can you paste an example how do I define if it's a POST or GET serializer.

Comment: I extended the answer. Please edit the question to add the requirement to get manufacturer details on GET.